# Jenkins, git clean permission denied error?

Tags: git, jenkins, permissions

Looking for some help with this. Tried to find solutions from similar problems but have found nothing that works.

My pipeline executes fine the first time, although upon a second build, I retrieve this error, `"git clean -ffdx" returned status code 1` , specifically...

```
using credential github

 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10

Fetching changes from the remote Git repository

 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/XXXXX/XXXXXX.git # timeout=10

Cleaning workspace

 > git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10

Resetting working tree

 > git reset --hard # timeout=10

 > git clean -ffdx # timeout=10

ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'

hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/XXXXXX/XXXXXX.git

    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:915)

    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1141)

    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1177)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:125)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:93)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:80)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)

    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git clean -ffdx" returned status code 1:

stdout: 

stderr: warning: failed to remove 1/src/build/table_select_window/PYZ-00.toc: Permission denied

warning: failed to remove 1/src/build/table_select_window/xref-table_select_window.html: Permission denied

warning: failed to remove 1/src/build/table_select_window/EXE-00.toc: Permission denied

warning: failed to remove 1/src/build/table_select_window/Analysis-00.toc: Permission denied

warning: failed to remove 1/src/build/table_select_window/PKG-00.pkg: Permission denied

warning: failed to remove 1/src/build/table_select_window/PKG-00.toc: Permission denied

warning: failed to remove 1/src/build/table_select_window/PYZ-00.pyz: Permission denied

warning: failed to remove 1/src/build/table_select_window/warn-table_select_window.txt: Permission denied

warning: failed to remove 1/src/build/table_select_window/base_library.zip: Permission denied

warning: failed to remove 1/src/dist/table_select_window: Permission denied

warning: failed to remove 1/src/__pycache__/table_select_window.cpython-37.pyc: Permission denied



    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2437)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2367)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2363)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1923)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1935)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.clean(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1017)

    at hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.CleanBeforeCheckout.decorateFetchCommand(CleanBeforeCheckout.java:45)

    at hudson.plugins.git.extensions.GitSCMExtension.decorateFetchCommand(GitSCMExtension.java:288)

    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:911)

    ... 11 more

Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
```

I have tried restarting my machine, as well as enabling 'clean before checkout' in Jenkins and have had no luck. I am running windows 10 and jenkins through docker. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: did you get anywhere with this I am having the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent this from happening in future builds, you can add the following to your jenkinsfile (to run after all stages).

```
post 
{
    always 
    {
        yumCleanUp()
        cleanWs()
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the plugin [Workspace Cleanup](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ws-cleanup/) is needed to run `cleanWs()`.